# How to add a traling slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, slash, trailing

I have the follow code in my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule  ^([a-z]{2})/([a-z]+)$  $2.php?lang=$1
```

How I add a trailing slash, so I can use http://www.liveandletdive.fi/en/contact/ instead of only http://www.liveandletdive.fi/en/contact ?

I figured out, how I can do my site with seo freindly urls, and multilingual. Only this small part remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([a-z]+)/?$  $2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: ok try updated code, your earlier rule needed an optional trailing slash.

Comment: Hi Anubhava
Thank You this works now as I need it.
Kindly Simon